# The proof of Hadamard inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

The proof of the inequality is given in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I do not know why he replaced $y_{j}$ with the **conjugate transpose** of $A$, I know he used the conjugate because the second term of the inner product must be conjugate but why the **transpose**? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: It is generaly discouraged posting math as pictures. Can you please rewrite this using MathJax?

Comment: As long as I have time I will do so .........I am so sorry for posting pictures @ThePirateBay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to write the matrix $B=(b_{ij})$ given by $b_{ij}=\langle y_i,y_j\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\overline{a_{jk}}$. We can assume that for any matrix $X=(x_{ij})$ we are dealing with, the index $i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ row, while the index $j$ denotes the $j^{th}$ column. One can easily verify that if $Z=XY$ is a matrix given by the product of two other matrixes, then the element $z_{ij}$ is

$$z_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n x_{ik}y_{kj}$$

just by using the definition of the product of matrixes. Now let us denote by $A^t=(a^t_{ij})$ the transpose of $A$. The elements of $A^t$ are $a^t_{ij}=a_{ji}$. Let $C=A\overline{A^t}$ with elements denoted by $c_{ij}$. Then we see that

$$b_{ij}=\langle y_i,y_j\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\overline{a_{jk}}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\overline{a^t_{kj}}=c_{ij},$$

where in the last equality we used the formula above for the element of a product of matrixes. So the desired $B=A\overline{A^t}$.